# Do you know a Chrome / Firefox extensions using IndexeDB and Local storage?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, local-storage, local, indexeddb

I need to see running examples of extensions for Chrome and Firefox
using :

1°) IndexeDB 
2°) Local storage

I d like to now if the files created by extensions in IndexeDB or "Local storage" have a filename 
different from the ones created by a website.

For "Local storage" in Chrome, file name starts with "chrome-extensions", 
and for IndexedDB ?
and for Firefox ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, extension and webpage data are always separated.

- IndexedDB in Firefox: extensions have their data in the `indexedDB/chrome` directory in the profile, webpages under `indexedDB/http+++example.com`.
- Local storage in Firefox: data is stored in the `webappsstore.sqlite` database, scope field determines the origin of the data. Extensions cannot use local storage.
- IndexedDB in Chrome: extensions have their data in the `IndexedDB/chrome-extension_...` directories in the profile, websites under `IndexedDB/http_...`.
- Local storage in Chrome: stored in the `Local Storage` directory in the profile. Files containing extension data start with `chrome-extension_`, files containing website data with `http_` or `https_`.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer !
Do you think that in the future, Local storages will be supported by Firefox extensions ?

Comment: @user382591: Unlikely - Firefox extensions have better mechanisms at their disposal.